# Converting statements into logical form. Am I on the right track?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, first-order-logic

Consider the following statements.

(i) I buy all interesting movies.

(ii) I have watched all movies by Wolfgang Petersen.

(iii) For any movie, either I buy it (i.e., buy its DVD) or watch it.

(iv) All interesting movies have a rating of more than 8 on imdb.com.

(v) The movie Troy has a rating of 7.5 on imdb.com.

Let M be the set of all movies. Let the boolean function I(m) return true if m is interesting. Similarly, consider other boolean functions B(m), W (m), P (m), E(m) to denote me having bought the movie, me having watched the movie, the movie made by W. Petersen, and the movie having an 8 plus rating.

(a) Write each of the above five statement in pure logical form using appropriate quantifications.

**i) ForAll m in M, B(m) —> I(m)**

**ii) ForAll m in M, P(m) —> W(m)**

**iii) ForAll m in M, B(m) OR W(m)**

**iv) ForAll m in M, I(m) —> E(m)**

**v) ThereExists a movie m in M (named Troy), such that ~E(m)**

(b) Can we conclude the statement “Troy is by Wolfgang Petersen”? [Hint: If p → q and r → s then (p ∪ r) ! (q ∪ s).] If yes, show the sequence of inferences. If not, justify your answer.

**Since all interesting movies have a rating of more than 8 on imdb.com, this means that there can be other movies that have a rating higher than 8 that are not interesting, and also means that all movies that have a rating of less than or equal to 8 are not interesting. Troy has a rating of 7.5 on imdb.com, which is less than 8, and therefore is not interesting. From (i) and (iii), Since Troy is not interesting, I did not buy it, and therefore must have watched it. Just because I have watched all movies by Wolfgang Petersen, that does not mean that I have never watched a movie that is not by him, so since I watched Troy, it could very well not be by Wolfgang Peterson. There is not enough information to conclude that Troy is by Wolfgang Petersen.**

Answer (score 0):

i) should be $\forall m \in M (I(m) \rightarrow B(m))$

for v), you should probably use a constant to denote the specific Troy movie .. so let's use $t$.  Then we get:  $\neg E(t)$ ('Troy did not get a rating above 8 on imdb)

Your explanation for b) needs to change a bit since you can't conclude that you don't buy any uninteresting movies.

Comment: About your last comment, I think I may be confused about what (i) is saying. Does it mean I buy only interesting movies or that I buy all possible interesting movies that exist?

Comment: @Hello i) is saying that you buy all interesting movies, so it is the latter. Put differently: if a movie is interesting, you will buy it.  If it is not interesting ... you may or may not buy it. So it is not necessarily true that you only buy interesting movies. Note that this also means that you may or may not have bought the Troy movie. All we can say about the Troy movie is that it is not interesting.

Comment: That's why I was confused. My answer for (i) was reversed like you said at first but I changed the answer last-minute. I will take a look at part b... thanks!

Comment: @Hello You're welcome!